# Requests : submitting a POST requests with dynamic form content

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm having trouble finding a way to send a POST request using the Requests module to login to my account since the username and password tags have dynamic random content : this is the original html input i'm trying to target :

```
  <input size="40" maxlength="64" name="1009750639" id="1009750639">
```

I can regex the name and password tag numbers and store them in variables (name_id / pass_id) but logging in fails when I try to submit this request :

```
 payload = {name_id:'xxxx@gmail.com', pass_id:'12345678'}
 requests.post(url , data=payload, headers=headers)
```

(url is a requests.Session() object)